# Find a sequence in $l_1$ that converge to a point in l_1 with supremum norm but not converge with $l_1$ norm

Tags: analysis

Find a sequence in $l_1$ that converge to a point in $l_1$ with supremum norm but not converge with $l_1$ norm

Answer (score 1):

If $e^{(n)}$ is the sequence with $1$ at $n$-place and zero elsewhere, set
$$
a^{(n)} := \frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^ne^{(k)}.
$$
Then $\|a^{(n)}\|_\infty = \frac 1n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ but $\|a^{(2n)}-a^{(n)}\|_1 = 1$ for each $n$.

Comment: A maybe slightly easier way to see that the given $a^{(n)}$ does not converge in the $l_1$ norm is to remember that for any $x \in l_1$ we have $\lVert x\rVert_\infty \le \lVert x\rVert_1$. So if $a^{(n)}$ would converge to some $l_1$ vector in the $l_1$ norm, it would have to converge to the same vector in the supremum-norm, so that limit must be the zero vector. So we only need to realize that $\forall n: \lVert a^{(n)}\rVert_1=1$ to understand that this is not true.
This gets around the need to find the nice trick to consider $\lVert a^{(2n)}-a^{(n)}\rVert_1$.