# convergences of series in two different metrics

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, absolute-convergence

for the past few days I've been studying the topic of metric spaces and now making some exercices on it. However I'm struggling with the following exercice: let $l^1(\mathbb{N})$ denote all function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |f(k)| < \infty$$
For $f,g \in l^1(\mathbb(\mathbb{N}))$ we look at the following metric
$$d_1(f,g) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |f(k)-g(k)| $$
$$d_{\infty}(f,g) = sup\{|f(k)-g(k)| | k \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
So I already proves that if $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $l^1(\mathbb{N})$ and $f \in l^1(\mathbb{N})$ that if $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ for the metric $d_1$, that is also converges for the metric $d_{\infty}$. The question now is if the reverse is also true so that if $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ for the metric $d_{\infty}$ does it also converge for the metric $d_1$. I think this is not true since taking an infinite sum over a small number gives you infinity, however I'm not able to come up with a counterexample. I also couldn't prove it. If you have any tips on how to solve this problem please let me know, any help would be grealty appreciated :))

Comment: $f_n(k)=\frac1 n$ if $k \leq n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a sequence in $l_1$ that converge to a point in l\_1 with supremum norm but not converge with $l_1$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394305/find-a-sequence-in-l-1-that-converge-to-a-point-in-l-1-with-supremum-norm-but)

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you!!

Comment: The duplicate gives the same counterexample, and proves it.